# Disable build window when building in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

How can I prevent the build window from showing in Sublime Text 2 whenever I make a build  with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default setting is in `Preferences.sublime-settings`in the `Default` bundle:

```
// Shows the Build Results panel when building. If set to false, the Build
// Results can be shown via the Tools/Build Results menu.
"show_panel_on_build": true,
```

You can either edit that, or add an override to your user settings (on OS X: *Sublime Text 2 » Preferences » Settings – User* or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>).

Comment: Is it possible disable it only with certain build schemes?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set it programmatically in Sublime Text 3 with some added logic, eg. show on errors only.

open and edit `\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default\exec.py`*
**note: Default.sublime-package is a renamed zip archive.*

notice these two functions

```
def on_data(self, proc, data):
    pass

def on_finished(self, proc):
    # some logic here
    self.window.run_command("hide_panel")
```

More reading [here](https://github.com/alexnj/SublimeOnSaveBuild/pull/8).