# Hide build results window in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2, window, build

After a build command (control + b) a window with results appear. Is there any way (not automatically but by shortcut or using another command) to hide it?

Comment: [This](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=35764&sid=12f860f3d46b1544a8cd8538d9616f4d#p35764) looks promsing

Comment: By the way, this has been asked before: https://superuser.com/questions/538636/disable-build-window-when-building-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd>‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏

Comment: Is there some option to prevent the console from being displayed in the first place?

Comment: To avoid showing the console in the first place: https://superuser.com/a/538648