# Unhide build output in Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text

After starting a build in Sublime Text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>), a pane with the output appears.

The output pane [can be hidden by <kbd>ESC</kbd>](https://superuser.com/a/764829/45737).
Buth how do I *unhide* the output pane again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shift+esc to unhide the output terminal on Sublime.

Answer (score 6):

In the latest build of Sublime Text (build 3020) there is a "Panel Switcher" in the lower left of the window.

See the icon in the bottom left. Click it and it shows a list of available output panels to open.

[image: Panel Switcher Screenshot]

Comment: Good answer. Note that plugins, such as Sublime SFTP automatically append themselves to this context menu.

Answer (score 4):

#### How do I unhide the output pane again?

1. Use "Tools" → "Build Results" → "Show Build Results", or
2. Create a new shortcut key of your choice as follows:

> As you can see in `Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu` the
>   command for "Show build results" is this:
>
> ```
> {
>   "command": "show_panel", 
>   "args": {
>     "panel": "output.exec"
>   },
>   "caption": "Show Build Results",
>   "mnemonic": "S"
> },
> ```
>
> so a custom key binding could be this:
>
> ```
> { 
>   "keys": ["ctrl+alt+super+r"],
>   "command": "show_panel", 
>   "args": {
>     "panel": "output.exec"
>   }
> }
> ```

Source [In Sublime Text 2 - reopen build output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10680736/3536342), answer by [akirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578588/akirk)

Comment: This is also available via the menu: **`Tools → Build Results → Show Build Results`**

Comment: Shortcut works perfectly! Thanks!